# Drupal google chart api Y axis values help needed

Tags: drupal, charts, google-visualization

I am using [chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart), a drupal module using [google chart tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/).

I have created the graph successfully but my problem is that I want to put integer values in the Y axis. I am making a graph of total number of votes. So let's suppose I have a poll with 55 votes (total nummer). The Y axis range should be till the max value property. Like if we have A, B and C then A has 25 votes, B has 10 votes and C has 20 votes. So the Y axis range should be equal to 25 with no float values like 1.5 or 2.5 between them. Here is the code of my function:

```
//theme the poll results block

  $html = $variables['results'];
  $pattern = "@class=\"text\"\>(.*)\</div\>@";
  preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $choices); //extract choices
  $pattern = "@style=\"width: (.*)%;\"@";
  preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $votes); //extract percentages
  $chart = array(
      '#chart_id' => 'poll_chart' . $variables[nid],
      '#type' => CHART_TYPE_BAR_V,
      '#size' => chart_size(600, 350),
      '#grid_lines' => chart_grid_lines(100,10 ),
      '#bar_size' => chart_bar_size(30, 50),
  );

// NEED TO FILL IN DATA TO MAKE CHART
  for ($c=0; $c < count($choices[1]); $c++) { //make labels and values
     $chart['#data_colors'][] = 'ff8e07';
     $chart['#data'][$choices[1][$c]] = $votes[1][$c]; //number of votes
     $chart['#legends'][] = $choices[1][$c] . " (" . $votes[1][$c] . "%)"; // labels
     $chart['#mixed_axis_labels'][CHART_AXIS_X_BOTTOM][0][] = chart_mixed_axis_label(t($choices[1][$c]))
     ;
     print $choice['chvotes'];
  }

  $chart['#mixed_axis_labels'][CHART_AXIS_X_BOTTOM][2][] = chart_mixed_axis_label(t('Choices'), 50);
  $chart['#mixed_axis_labels'][CHART_AXIS_Y_LEFT][3][] = chart_mixed_axis_label(t('Votes'), 95);
  $chart['#mixed_axis_labels'][CHART_AXIS_Y_LEFT][4][] = chart_mixed_axis_range_label(0, $variables['votes']);

  $variables['results'] = chart_render($chart); //render graph
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply described in https://www.drupal.org/node/536472, then the sample shown in https://www.drupal.org/node/536472#comment-2127622 can be used to address this question.